# How to filter BuddyPress member loop by ACF field?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, buddypress

PHP newb here, looking for some guidance. I am working with BuddyPress and Advanced Custom Fields (ACF). I have an ACF field 'new_user' with a value of true/false. I am trying to filter my BuddyPress Members Loop to only display users with a value of 'new_user' = true.

There are 2 code samples here.

1. The standard BP Members Loop. My thought here, is how do I first query my users by ACF ‘new_user’ = true and then start the bp member loop?:

> ```
> if ( bp_has_members() ) : 
> // some code goes here 
> endif; 
>
> while ( bp_members() ) : bp_the_member(); 
> //OUTPUT MEMBERS LIST HERE
> endwhile;
> ```

2. This is a BP function to filter by Buddypress extended user fields. The idea here I believe is to replace the code in the middle specific to xprofile_get_field with the proper ACF code:

   function my_custom_ids( $field_name, $field_value = '' ) {

   ```
     if ( empty( $field_name ) )
       return '';

     global $wpdb;

     $field_id = xprofile_get_field_id_from_name( $field_name ); 

     if ( !empty( $field_id ) ) 
       $query = "SELECT user_id FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "bp_xprofile_data WHERE field_id = " . $field_id;
     else
      return '';

     if ( $field_value != '' ) 
       $query .= " AND value LIKE '%" . $field_value . "%'";
         /* 
         LIKE is slow. If you're sure the value has not been serialized, you can do this:
         $query .= " AND value = '" . $field_value . "'";
         */

     $custom_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $query );

     if ( !empty( $custom_ids ) ) {
       // convert the array to a csv string
       $custom_ids_str = 'include=' . implode(",", $custom_ids);
       return $custom_ids_str;
     }
     else
      return '';

   }
   ```

Of course, I am open to solving this in another way as well. I hope this is clear.